# class object name is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to doctest an initialization of a class. and when i do i get the error that name is not defined.

for example i had to do same thing for class Rat and below is my code:

```
class Rat:
    """ A rat caught in a maze. """

    def __init__(self, symbol, row, col):
        """(Rat, str, int, int) - > NoneType

        A rat with a symbol J or P donating who they are and row and col donating their position.

        >>> rat_1 = Rat(RAT_1_CHAR, 1, 1)
        >>> rat_2 = Rat(RAT_2_CHAR, 1, 2)
        >>> rat_1.symbol
        'J'
```

This works fine, now when i do the same for Class maze below i get the answer maze is not defined when i run a doctest. What is the difference between these 2 and why does 1 over the other work?

```
class Maze:
    """ A 2D maze. """

    def __init__(self, structure, rat_1, rat_2):
        """(Maze, list of list of str, Rat, Rat) -> NoneType

        >>> maze = Maze([['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'], ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'], ['#', '.', '.', '@', '#', '.', '#'], ['#', '@', '#', '.', '@', '.', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']], Rat('J', 1, 1), Rat('P', 1, 4))
        >>> maze.rat_1
        Rat('J', 1, 1)
        """

        self.structure = structure
        self.rat_1 = rat_1
        self.rat_2 = rat_2
```

entire error below:

File "**main**", line 7, in **main**.Maze.**init**
Failed example:
    maze = Maze([[xxxx],[xxxx]], Rat('J', 1, 1), Rat('P', 1, 4))
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mobasher\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "", line 1, in 
        maze = Maze([[xxxx],[xxxx]], Rat('J', 1, 1), Rat('P', 1, 4))
    NameError: name 'xxxx' is not defined

---

File "**main**", line 8, in **main**.Maze.**init**
Failed example:
    maze.rat_1
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\mobasher\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "", line 1, in 
        maze.rat_1
    NameError: name 'maze' is not defined

---

1 items had failures:
   2 of   2 in **main**.Maze.**init**
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a little while to write the parts of the code you were missing but I don't see any issue and I got a lot of errors with your code but none of them appeared to match the error you stated.

```
class Rat:
    """ A rat caught in a maze. """

    def __init__(self, symbol, row, col):
        """(Rat, str, int, int) - > NoneType

        A rat with a symbol J or P donating who they are and row and col donating their position.

        >>> rat_1 = Rat('J', 1, 1)
        >>> rat_2 = Rat('P', 1, 2)
        >>> rat_1.symbol
        'J'
        """
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        pass
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Rat(\'{}\', {}, {})'.format(self.symbol, self.row, self.col)
class Maze:
    """ A 2D maze. """

    def __init__(self, structure, rat_1, rat_2):
        """(Maze, list of list of str, Rat, Rat) -> NoneType

        >>> maze = Maze([['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'], ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'], ['#', '.', '.', '@', '#', '.', '#'], ['#', '@', '#', '.', '@', '.', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']], Rat('J', 1, 1), Rat('P', 1, 4))
        >>> maze.rat_1
        Rat('J', 1, 1)
        """

        self.structure = structure
        self.rat_1 = rat_1
        self.rat_2 = rat_2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

If you post your whole error I can explain why my solution works for that error, but everything appears to work.

Comment: thanks, have updated post to include entire error msg i get for the doctest.

Comment: The first error caused the second error. So you your question is based on the wrong error. The first error you pasted failed because `xxxx` is undefined. You need to pass a meaningful value. `maze` doesn't exist because the constructor failed.

Comment: @Sam also if this answered your question please mark it as an answer.

Comment: sorry, no it did not answer my q. The above code does indeed run without any errors. But i am struggling to see why that is the case. The maze code is the same, whilst the only difference revolves around what is in the Rat class. Also not clear the purpose of adding the __repr__ code. How is it that addition makes the code run? If i copy my code to a new window, it finds maze but instead of the expected     Rat('J', 1, 1), it got: <__main__.Rat object at 0x000000000AE83978>

Comment: @Sam Classes don't automatically print `Rat('J', 1, 1)`. If you want it to output in this manner you need to override the `__repr__` method. Otherwise it just prints the object as in your case: `<__main__.Rat object at 0x000000000AE83978>`. The `Maze` was failing because the `Rat` was failing because your check tried to match a string output.

Comment: if i run the Rat class by itself, no errors are received though. When i do the doctest, i stipulate that rat_1 = Rat(Rat_1_CHAR, 1, 1). So when i go to call rat_1.symbol -> this will indeed return the symbol associated with Rat_1_CHAR. This appears to work. yet employing the same method for maze does not, so i dont understand if Rat is failing when i run it on its own why do i not see the doctest error?

Comment: Yes but there is a test you don't do in `Rat` that you do do in `Maze`: `maze.rat_1`. That line calls the `__repr__` method from `Rat`. Call `rat_1` in `Rat` and you will see the same error.